# Line breaks in Print and PutAppend

Tags: output-formatting

This is probably a simple-minded question, but I've tried many things that haven't worked. In the output below, how does one add a line break before "points=..."? It will also need to work in PutAppend.

```
iter=3;
points={{0,0},{2,6},{0,6},{5,7}};
Print["iter=", iter, "points=", points]
```

Comment: `..."\npoints="...
`

Comment: This works for Print but unfortunately not for PutAppend.

Comment: `PutAppend["test", "this", "C:/temp/temp.txt"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will be close enough to what you want.

```
iter = 3;
points = {{0, 0}, {2, 6}, {0, 6}, {5, 7}};
tmp = StringTemplate["``=``"]
Do[Print[tmp[s, ToExpression@s]], {s, {"iter", "points"}}]
Do[PutAppend[tmp[s, ToExpression@s], "C:/temp/temp.txt"], {s, {"iter", "points"}}]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Sometimes I pine for the simplicity of Fortran-like I/O.